# Unsupported top level event type "onGestureHandlerStateChange" dispatched

Tags: react-native

I have a problem with my react-native app. I have upgrade to last react-native (0.61.4) and updated my android SDK to 28 (for publish on google play).

But I have an error when I click on some buttons which have animations.

> Invariant Violation: Unsupported top level event type "onGestureHandlerStateChange" dispatched

My react-native app works well with android SDK 27 (without change package.json)

My main packages:

```
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "^0.61.4",
"react-navigation": "^3.11.1",
"react-navigation-drawer": "^2.3.3",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.0",
"react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
"react-navigation-tabs": "^2.5.6",
```

I have tried to update react-navigation, or try https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/320#issuecomment-443815828 but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue too in production on Android after upgrading RN0.61.4.

Now it's fix, basicaly it's due to asynchronous loading of the JS.
The handler was registered too late and thus throwing this error.

So to fix it, add this in your main entry (index.js):

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  const { UIManager } = NativeModules;
  if (UIManager) {
    // Add gesture specific events to genericDirectEventTypes object exported from UIManager native module.
    // Once new event types are registered with react it is possible to dispatch these events to all kind of native views.
    UIManager.genericDirectEventTypes = {
      ...UIManager.genericDirectEventTypes,
      onGestureHandlerEvent: { registrationName: 'onGestureHandlerEvent' },
      onGestureHandlerStateChange: {
        registrationName: 'onGestureHandlerStateChange',
      },
    };
  }
}
```

I hope it will help you.